# find('all') doing unexpected (unwanted) SQL join in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I've set up two models: city, and country. Below is how I've defined them:

```
class City extends AppModel { // for "cities" table
    public $hasOne = 'Country';
}

class Country extends AppModel { // for "countries" table
    public $hasMany = array(
        'City' => array(
            'className' => 'City'
        )
    );
}
```

and in my controller:

```
public function getCities() {
  $this->loadModel('City');
  $cities = $this->City->find('all');
}
```

but it's giving me this error:

```
Database Error

Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Country.city_id' in 'on clause'

SQL Query: SELECT `City`.`id`, `City`.`country_id`, `City`.`name`, `City`.`latitude`, `City`.`longitude`, `City`.`time_zone`, `City`.`dma_id`, `City`.`code`, `City`.`created`, `City`.`modified`, `Country`.`id`, `Country`.`country_id`, `Country`.`name`, `Country`.`code`, `Country`.`created`, `Country`.`modified` FROM `rtynbiz_ls`.`cities` AS `City` LEFT JOIN `rtynbiz_ls`.`countries` AS `Country` ON (`Country`.`city_id` = `City`.`id`) WHERE 1 = 1

Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app/View/Errors/pdo_error.ctp
```

I can't understand why it's trying to do a join with Country table. I only want to fetch cities. How do I stop this from happening? And, why is it trying to make an association using Country.city_id (which doesn't exists) Also, have I named my classes and tables correctly? Thanks

Comment: you have has many relationship for countries and hasOne for cities. Simply remove them then you will get only citites.

Comment: Yeh that works, thanks. But are these not required if I want to fetch cities for a country? I'm coming from Rails, in Rails you define in a similar manner and let's you do something like `cities = country.cities`. What is the point of defining hasOne and hasMany in CakePHP then?

Comment: $belongsTo!! Sorry, I meant to use this instead of $hasOne. That's the relationship I was wanting.

Answer (score 0):

Following lines of code are making relationship so JOIN is present there. To remove the JOIN from  the query just replace :

```
class City extends AppModel { // for "cities" table
    public $hasOne = 'Country';
}

class Country extends AppModel { // for "countries" table
    public $hasMany = array(
        'City' => array(
            'className' => 'City'
        )
    );
}
```

With:

```
  class City extends AppModel { }// for "cities" table

  class Country extends AppModel {} // for "countries" table
```

You can make relationships in the tables easily by following [this](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models.html)

Answer (score 0):

By default, CakePHP will automatically try to pull additional model's data.  To stop that from being the default, in your AppModel, set this variable:

```
public $recursive = -1;
```

I would also suggest adding Containable behavior, so your app model looks like this:

```
<?php
class AppModel extends Model {
    public $actsAs = array('Containable');
    public $recursive = -1;
}
```

Read more about "recursive" and "Containable Behavior" at the [CakePHP book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you **don't want to do join** when you want to retrieve your data make it recursive -1

```
public function get_cities() {
     $this->loadModel('City');
     $this->City->recursive=-1;
     $cities = $this->City->find('all');
     //or
     $cities = $this->City->find('all', array('recursive'=>-1));
}
```

any way this would be your model:

```
class Country extends AppModel {
     public $hasMany = array(
        'City' => array(
            'className' => 'City',
            'foreignKey' => 'country_id',
            'dependent' => false,
        ),
     );
}

class City extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Country' => array(
            'className' => 'Country',
            'foreignKey' => 'country_id',
        )
    );
}
```

make sure you don't have messy code on these 2 models